# How can I customize the color of the Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I am BRAND new to iOS development and am building my first app using Xcode 4.3.2 for iOS5. I am also using storyboards.

I want the background color of my navigation bar to be black instead of the default blue color for all of my views in the storyboard. I have researched everywhere and cannot find anything that works. Either the code generates error messages or its not clear (to me) where to put it. Can anyone help?!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please provide more details as your attempts and the error messages you've encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarImg.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Also check out this [-link-](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) for more info relating to your question.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure where to put this? I was under the assumption that I need to write code into the app delegate or in a custom class...but in either/any case I still need a bit more information since I'm so new to this.

Comment: @user1697845 I added a link in my answer that will provide more info on the topic.